# Como posso tratar exceção constraint violation para mostrar ao usuário de forma amigável

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Qual a melhor forma de tratar uma exceção de Integrity constraint violation para explicar de forma amigável ao usuário ?

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente, você poderá usar um `try/catch` para capturar uma exceção específica.

```
try {

   Model::operations()->save();

} catch (\PDOException $e) {

    return redirect()->back()->withErrors('message', 'Erro ao realizar a operação');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Outra solução seria você usar *QueryException*, primeiro você precisa "chamar" a classe no seu *controller*:

```
use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;
```

Depois você pode usar da seguinte forma:

```
try {
        $dados = MinhaModel::findOrFail($id);
        $dados->delete();
    } catch (QueryException $e) {
        dd($e->getMessage());
    }
```

Para retornar a exceção de forma amigável para o usuário faça o seguinte:

```
try {
        $dados = MinhaModel::findOrFail($id);
        $dados->delete();
    } catch (QueryException $e) {
        flash()->error('Mensagem para o usuário');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Para notificações de erro eu uso a biblioteca *laracasts/flash*

```
https://github.com/laracasts/flash
```

Comment: Acabei de editar a resposta com tudo que você precisa.

Comment: +1 creio que essa forma seja a melhor, mas não estava lembrando o "caminho" do QueryException (namespace grande, não gravei)